# Datagridview horizontal scroll does not go all the way across data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I often run into this problem where when using a datagridview, if I need to make use of a horizontal scroll, it will not go to the end of the form.  The last column is then rendered inaccessible.  I can usually cheat by extending the size of the dgv or starting the form maximized, but if the vertical scroll works as expected (goes all the way down to the last record in the dataset), why doesn't the horizontal?

```
private void InitializeMemberGrid()
    {
        // Set grid properties
        this.grdMembers.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.grdMembers.RowHeadersVisible = true;
        this.grdMembers.Columns.Clear();
        mPicWaiting = PartD.Windows.Common.Utility.AddWaitingImage(this.grdMembers);
        mPicWaiting.Visible = false;

        // Member ID Column
        var colMemberID = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colMemberID.Name = "MemberID";
        colMemberID.HeaderText = "Member ID";
        colMemberID.DataPropertyName = "ID";
        this.grdMembers.Columns.Add(colMemberID);

        //// Contract ID Column
        var colContractID = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colContractID.Name = "ContractID";
        colContractID.HeaderText = "Contract ID";
        colContractID.DataPropertyName = "ContractID";
        this.grdMembers.Columns.Add(colContractID);

        // SSN Column
        var colSSN = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colSSN.Name = "SSN";
        colSSN.HeaderText = "SSN";
        colSSN.DataPropertyName = "SSN";
        this.grdMembers.Columns.Add(colSSN);

        // HICN Column
        var colHICN = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colHICN.Name = "HICN";
        colHICN.HeaderText = "HICN";
        colHICN.DataPropertyName = "HICN";
        this.grdMembers.Columns.Add(colHICN);

        // Name Column
        var colName = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colName.Name = "Name";
        colName.HeaderText = "Name";
        colName.DataPropertyName = "LastNameFirstName";
        colName.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        this.grdMembers.Columns.Add(colName);

        // DOB Column
        var colDOB = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colDOB.Name = "DOB";
        colDOB.HeaderText = "DOB";
        colDOB.DataPropertyName = "DateOfBirth";
        colDOB.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        this.grdMembers.Columns.Add(colDOB);

        // Retirement Date Column
        var colRetireDate = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colRetireDate.Name = "RetireDate";
        colRetireDate.HeaderText = "Retirement";
        colRetireDate.DataPropertyName = "RetireDate";
        this.grdMembers.Columns.Add(colRetireDate);

        // RelCode Column
        var colRelCode = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colRelCode.Name = "RelCode";
        colRelCode.HeaderText = "Rel";
        colRelCode.DataPropertyName = "RelCode";
        this.grdMembers.Columns.Add(colRelCode);

        // Resend Column
        var colResend = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colResend.Name = "Resend";
        colResend.HeaderText = "Resend";
        colResend.DataPropertyName = "Resend";
        this.grdMembers.Columns.Add(colResend);

        // Sent Column
        var colSent = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colSent.Name = "Sent";
        colSent.HeaderText = "Sent";
        colSent.DataPropertyName = "SubmissionCount";
        this.grdMembers.Columns.Add(colSent);

        // Status Column
        var colStatus = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colStatus.Name = "Status";
        colStatus.HeaderText = "Status";
        colStatus.DataPropertyName = "Status";
        this.grdMembers.Columns.Add(colStatus);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have probably set the width of the `DataGridView` instead of docking the control within the form.

Make sure the control looks right in the designer and then anchor it on the right hand side. This will stop the end column being chopped off if the form is resized. Better still, add a panel to embed your control in and dock it accordingly.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It is anchored on all sides so when maximized, it works fine.  My goal is to get the horizontal scroll to work properly WITHOUT resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the last column's "AutoSizeMode" property to "AllCells" fixed it for me:

```
column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
```